# Evitar palabras cortas y/o monosílabos MySQL LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un buscador en php que comunica con la base de datos MySQL y muestra los registros relacionados.

Para ello tengo esta consulta que funciona perfectamente:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE '%.$variablePHP.%'
```

Donde `$variblePHP` es la cadena que el usuario utiliza como término de búsqueda.

Pero en caso de no añadir ninguna palabra como filtro me devolvería todos los registros de la base de datos, si coloco monosílabos o palabras muy cortas también me devuelve un número muy elevado de registros.

¿Cómo podría controlar para que el filtro no devuelva ningún resultado a no ser que tenga al menos 3 caracteres?

Mi pregunta está enfocada a sentencias de MySQL si las hubiera ya que podría hacerlo con PHP pero no es el objetivo.

Comment: hacerlo con php seria el metodo correcto. Porque querrias sobrecargar a la base de datos para que haga calculos cuando no va a ejecutar la consulta?

Comment: puedes hacerlo con la funcion `count` y `str_split()` ejemplo `if(count(str_split($variablePHP)) >= 3){ //codigo a ejecutar}`

Comment: Y si le agregas un LIMIT a la consulta cuando te retorne demasiados datos, para que no te retorne muchos lógicamente..

Comment: una condición con `strlen($variablePHP) >= 3 || $variablePHP = ''` te servirá. Aunque si son muchos registros te convendría paginarlos donde los muestres.